# Is there an application to check a site for infections?

Tags: security, website, anti-virus

A friend of mine says that a site I frequent was reported by his antivirus software to be infected with a trojan.  I can't confirm this because I'm on a Mac, and he's running PC so nothing happens on my end.

I'm wondering if there's a web site that I could use to check the site for infection or malicious script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enter an url on http://online.us.drweb.com/?url=1, it allows you to scan it without actually having to open the url. It checks for malicious software and script.

Comment: Came up clean, I suspect it was a previous infection that just coincidentally was caught by his antivirus upon visiting the site.  many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try [Web of Trust](http://www.mywot.com/) and [McAfee SiteAdvisor](http://www.siteadvisor.com/).

*Also...*

> I can't confirm this because I'm on a Mac, and he's running PC so nothing happens on my end.

Or you are oblivious of a trojan running on your Mac. Unfortunately most of the people I know who run Mac don't install antiviruses, under the false impression that they are immune to all malware. This is far from the case and viruses are abundant despite this false sense of security upheld by advertising hype, misinformation and plain ignorance. I was once a junior system admin at a Macintosh-only office, the amount of malware I discovered that had collected on the network was unbelievable.

Play it safe. Practice [safe hex](http://www.claymania.com/safe-hex.html).

Comment: Appreciate the advice.  For my case, I only visit a small circle of trusted sites.  The site, as I suspected, was reported error free and the PC had been previously infected.